# Elements on the wrong positions

Tags: javascript, php, canvas, draw, iso

Why elements(buildings) displays on the wrong positions. I use same code after click as after download from base.

This code i use after drop element(building). This code work good.

```
else if (build[row] != null && build[row][col] != null) {
        tilePositionY -= building.height - tile.height;
            tilePositionX -= (building.width / 2) - (tile.width / 2);
        context.drawImage(building, Math.round(tilePositionX), Math.round(tilePositionY), building.width, building.height);
}
```

This code i use after download from base

```
if (oldBuild[row] && oldBuild[row][col]){
    tilePositionY -= building.height - tile.height;
    tilePositionX -= (building.width / 2) - (tile.width / 2);
        context.drawImage(building, Math.round(tilePositionX), Math.round(tilePositionY), building.width, building.height);
}
```

ajax request

```
var oldBuild = [];

                $.ajax({
                    type     : "GET",
                    url      : "dane.php",
                    async    : false,
                    success : function(msg) {
                        oldBuild = msg;
                    }
                });
```

dane.php

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test");
$return=[];
while($RES = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
    if(!isset($return[$RES['row']]))
    $return[$RES['row']]=[];
    $return[$RES['row']][$RES['col']]= true; //albo rodzaj budynku
}
echo json_encode($return, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

Comment: Shorten your code please. Why dont u ask something fundamental e.g. the syntax of something rather than asking to solve the problem as a whole.

Comment: I have 1 record on the base. I need display this record(element) on the good tile. In the base i have id, name, row, col. I must display this element on the same row and col.

Comment: Edit your question. that would serve you get an answer from others..